# how to run GPU function in parallel? BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to run `run_BMAP_SGD_gpu()` with different batch size but fails. I've seen [pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/multiprocessing.html#cuda-in-multiprocessing) but didn't understand properly to adapt to my problem.
could you pls help?

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = list(executor.map(run_for_batch_size, bsizes))
```

This is description of the error

```
/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py in __get_result(self)
    401         if self._exception:
    402             try:
--> 403                 raise self._exception
    404             finally:
    405                 # Break a reference cycle with the exception in self._exception

BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

Please see below full reproducible with import modules

```
#load modules
import torch
import torch.distributions as dist
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time as tm
import importlib
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

#from scripts.functions_SGD_linear_Regression import add_bias, createBatches,pred_y, residualsPerBatch, run_BMAP_SGD_gpu, sim_XY, train_test_split

#user parameters 
#1. simulate data
Data = False
N = 700 #nsamples 
P = 3 #n features

#algorithms settings
# nIterations_main = 10 #set niterations to converge
nIterations_main = 9000000 #set niterations to converge
set_rhoT = 1e-8
set_nMiniBatches = 5
set_dev2Use = "cuda"
set_batchSize = 400
set_prior_beta_var_lambda = 10
set_tol = 1e-6

#run program with minimum hyperparamters
fastRun = True

# nMiniBatches_main=set_nMiniBatches, dev2Use = set_dev2Use, batchSize_main=set_batchSize, nIter=nIterations_main, rhoT=set_rhoT, tol=set_tol, prior_beta_var_lambda=set_prior_beta_var_lambda, add_biasX=False, optimize=False)

torch.multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')# multiprocesing

##########################################################################################
#############################functions
##########################################################
def sim_XY(N, P, mu=0.0, scale=1.0, returnXY = True):
    #generate normal dist data
    m = dist.normal.Normal(torch.tensor([mu]), torch.tensor([scale]))
    X = m.sample((N,P)).squeeze().to("cuda")
    ones_column = torch.ones((X.shape[0],1)).to("cuda")
    print(f"shape ones_column, {ones_column.shape}")
    X_plusOnes=torch.hstack([ones_column, X])
    print(f"shape X_plusOnes, {X_plusOnes.shape}")
    alpha_true = dist.Normal(0.0, 1.0).sample([N]).to("cuda")
    print(f"shape X_plusOnes, {X_plusOnes.shape}")
    beta_true = dist.Normal(0.0, 1.0).sample((P+1, 1)).squeeze().to("cuda")
    print(f"beta_true.shape; {beta_true.shape}")
    sigma_true = dist.Exponential(1.0).sample().to("cuda")
    eps = dist.Normal(0.0, sigma_true).sample([N]).to("cuda")
    #y = alpha_true + X @ beta_true #+ eps #already factored in
    y = X_plusOnes @ beta_true #+ eps
    print(f"y.shape; {y.shape}")
    if returnXY is True:
        Y = y.unsqueeze(1)  # Add a dimension to make it (100, 1)
        XY = torch.cat((X, Y), dim = 1)
        print(f"XY.shape {XY.shape} last column is Y\n")
        return XY, beta_true
    else:
        return X, y, beta_true


def train_test_split(data, train_size, nObs_Global):
    if train_size >= 1:
        train_size = 0.7
    train_size = int(train_size * nObs_Global)
    tmp_size = nObs_Global - train_size
    test_size = int(0.60 * tmp_size)
    val_size = tmp_size - test_size
    train_dataset, validation_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(data, [train_size, val_size, test_size])
    #train_dataset.dataset #do this to access datas
    return train_dataset, validation_dataset, test_dataset


## Create functions for SGD linear regression BMAP
def createBatches(XY_dataset, nBatches, batchSize):
    """
    #returns tensor of nBatches for XY data
    batchSize; #obs
    nBatches: N times subset of data
    """
    nSamplesGlobal=XY_dataset.shape[0]
    nFeatures=XY_dataset.shape[1]
    #batch size can't be more than total number of observa
    if batchSize >= nSamplesGlobal:
        batchSize = nSamplesGlobal
    #empty tensors to store results
    results_tensor = torch.zeros((nBatches, batchSize, nFeatures), device="cuda")
    for i in range(nBatches):
        indices = torch.randperm(nSamplesGlobal)[:batchSize].to("cuda")
        result = XY_dataset[indices]
        results_tensor[i] = result
    #print(f"batch_tensor.shape: {results_tensor.shape} created")
    return results_tensor


#compute y predictions for each batch
# @jit(target_backend='cuda')
def pred_y(computed_betas_batch, X_batch):
    y_batch_predictions = torch.matmul(X_batch, computed_betas_batch)
    return y_batch_predictions

# @jit(target_backend='cuda')
def residualsPerBatch(X_batch, y_batch_predictions, y_batch_true):
    #batchSize_gradient=len(X_batch)
    resid = torch.matmul(torch.sub(y_batch_true, y_batch_predictions), X_batch)
    return resid

##Mean-sqaured error  == sigma^2  of each batch
def mse_inSampleVarianceBatch(interceptXYData=None, yhatBatch=None):
    m=interceptXYData.shape[0] #number of obervation
    P=interceptXYData.shape[1] - 1 #intercept is part of Xtable
    samples_sigmaSquared = 1/(m - P - 1) * torch.sum(yhatBatch) #subtract 1
    return samples_sigmaSquared

#for each batch compute data_log_likelihood; #sigma_data = mse_inSampleVariance
def inSample_LLD_Btach(interceptXYData_Batch, yhatBatch=None, sigma_data = None, constant_sigma = False):
    #sigma_data = mse_inSampleVariance
    if constant_sigma is True:
        sigma_data = 1
    m=interceptXYData_Batch.shape[0] #number of obervation
    #computes; out_of_sample or in-sample log_likelihood
    data_LLD = (-(1 / m)) * torch.sum((1/ (2 * sigma_data)) * torch.square(yhatBatch - interceptXYData_Batch[..., -1]))
    return data_LLD


  
#calculate the gradient
def compute_grad_allBatches(nMiniBatches_main, XY_allBatches, nObserEntireDataset,  beta_sgd, lambda_val, return_predExp_EachMiniBatch = False):
    nFeaturesX = XY_allBatches.shape[2] - 1
    predictedExpectations = torch.zeros((nMiniBatches_main, XY_allBatches.shape[1])).to("cuda")
    storeResiduals = torch.zeros((nMiniBatches_main, nFeaturesX)).to("cuda")
    LogLiklihoodData_Per_Batch = torch.zeros((nMiniBatches_main)).to("cuda")
    for i in range(XY_allBatches.shape[0]):
        y_predBatch = torch.matmul(XY_allBatches[i][:, :-1], beta_sgd)
        yTrue_yHat_Batch = torch.sub(XY_allBatches[i][..., -1], y_predBatch)
        residualsBatch = torch.matmul(yTrue_yHat_Batch, XY_allBatches[i][:, :-1])
        storeResiduals[i] = residualsBatch
        predictedExpectations[i] = y_predBatch
        mseBatch=mse_inSampleVarianceBatch(interceptXYData=XY_allBatches[i], yhatBatch=y_predBatch)
        data_lld_batch=inSample_LLD_Btach(interceptXYData_Batch=XY_allBatches[i], yhatBatch=y_predBatch, sigma_data = mseBatch, constant_sigma = False)
        LogLiklihoodData_Per_Batch[i] = data_lld_batch
    AvgLogLikelihoodDataPerIter = torch.mean(LogLiklihoodData_Per_Batch)
    AvgLogLikelihoodDataPerIter=AvgLogLikelihoodDataPerIter.detach()
    predictedExpectationsSummedAcrossBatches = torch.sum(predictedExpectations, dim = 0)
    predictedExpectationsSummedAcrossBatches=predictedExpectationsSummedAcrossBatches.detach()    
    predictedExpectations=predictedExpectations.detach()
    #compute gradient    
    lambda_decay = (-1/torch.square(torch.Tensor([lambda_val]))).to("cuda")
    first_term = lambda_decay * beta_sgd
    second_term = (nObserEntireDataset/nMiniBatches_main) * torch.sum(storeResiduals, dim = 0)
    grad = first_term + second_term
    if return_predExp_EachMiniBatch is True:
        return grad, predictedExpectations, AvgLogLikelihoodDataPerIter
    else:
        return grad, predictedExpectationsSummedAcrossBatches, AvgLogLikelihoodDataPerIter



#main function to run SGD
def run_BMAP_SGD_gpu(intercept_XY_data, nMiniBatches_main=None, dev2Use = None, batchSize_main=None, nIter=None, rhoT=None, tol=None, prior_beta_var_lambda=None, add_biasX=False, optimize=False):
    #main function
    nObserEntireDataset = intercept_XY_data.shape[0]
    nFeaturesX = intercept_XY_data.shape[1] - 1

    #inistialize beta
    betaRandom = torch.rand(nFeaturesX, device = dev2Use)
    beta_holder = torch.zeros((int(nIter), nFeaturesX))
    trainLLDs_holder = torch.zeros((int(nIter)))
    #beta_holder = torch.zeros((int(nIter), nFeaturesX), device="cuda")
    beta_holder[0] = betaRandom
    #print(f"betaRandom.shape; {betaRandom.shape}")
    #print(f"beta_holder.shape; {beta_holder.shape}")
    #print(f"batch_XY[:, :, :-1]; {batch_XY[:, :, :-1].shape}")

    iter = 1
    while iter < nIter:
      batch_XY = createBatches(XY_dataset = intercept_XY_data, batchSize=batchSize_main, nBatches=nMiniBatches_main)
      #compute gradient; compute_grad_allBatches(nMiniBatches_main, XY_allBatches, nObserEntireDataset, nbatches, beta_sgd, lambda_val):
      gradients, expY, trainLLDs = compute_grad_allBatches(nMiniBatches_main=nMiniBatches_main, nObserEntireDataset=nObserEntireDataset, XY_allBatches=batch_XY, beta_sgd=beta_holder[iter-1].to(dev2Use), lambda_val=prior_beta_var_lambda)
      trainLLDs_holder[iter-1] = trainLLDs
      betas = beta_holder[iter-1].to(dev2Use) + ((rhoT) * gradients) #follow stochastic gradient
      beta_holder[iter] = betas #keep track of betas
      #print(f"betas; {betas}\n")
      
      #check for convergence with l2 norm strategy
      if iter > 1 and torch.linalg.norm(beta_holder[iter-1].to(dev2Use) - beta_holder[iter-2].to(dev2Use)) <= tol:
        print(f'Converged at iteration {iter}')
        if optimize == True:
          return iter
        else:
          return trainLLDs_holder[:iter], beta_holder[:iter+1, :], expY, iter
      iter+=1
    print(f"Convergence not achieved within the specified iterations.\n")
    if optimize == True:
        return iter
    else:
        return trainLLDs_holder[:iter], beta_holder[:iter+1, :], expY, iter

#run algorithm
if Data is False:
    XY, true_betas = sim_XY(N=N, P=P, mu=0.0, scale=1.0, returnXY = True)


#split data into train test
train_dataset, validation_dataset, test_dataset = train_test_split(data=XY, train_size=0.8, nObs_Global=XY.shape[0])
intercept_XY = train_dataset.dataset
intercept_XY_ = train_dataset.dataset


############Plot: influnce of batch sizes & rhoT on optimization
print(f"\nAnalyzing Influnce of batch sizes & rhoT on optimization")
bsizes = torch.arange(start=50, end=intercept_XY.shape[0], step=50)
bsizes

if fastRun is True:
    bsizes = bsizes[-2:]

#run sgd for different values of bsizes
iters_results_4batchSize = torch.zeros_like(bsizes)

def run_for_batch_size(v):
    print(f"Running computation with batch size: {v}")
    iter_returned = run_BMAP_SGD_gpu(intercept_XY_data=intercept_XY, nMiniBatches_main=v, dev2Use=set_dev2Use, batchSize_main=set_batchSize, nIter=nIterations_main, rhoT=set_rhoT, tol=set_tol, prior_beta_var_lambda=set_prior_beta_var_lambda, add_biasX=False, optimize=True)
    print(f"iter_returned {iter_returned} for batch size {v}")
    return iter_returned
# Running the loop in parallel using ProcessPoolExecutor
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = list(executor.map(run_for_batch_size, bsizes))
# Storing the results back into iters_results_4batchSize
for i, result in enumerate(results):
    iters_results_4batchSize[i] = result
    print(f"done computing with batch size of {bsizes[i]}")
```

Comment: Cuda multiprocessing is usually used for multi-GPU inference. Trying to run multiple processes on the same GPU can lead to issues